# Jquery how to run a function only if condition is true

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that check if CSS value exists,
the problem is that I need the function to work only when the CSS class exists,
currently the function running all the time because I'm using else condition (that need to re do the if condition).

```
 //use for @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) detection    
 $(window).resize(function(){
    if ($('#mobile-view').css('visibility') === 'hidden') {
        $("#product-gallery").insertAfter("#product-info");
    }
     else { 
         $("#product-info").insertAfter("#product-gallery");
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `:hidden` pseudo selector:

```
if ($('#mobile-view').is(':hidden')) {
    $("#product-gallery").insertAfter("#product-info");
} else {
    $("#product-info").insertAfter("#product-gallery");
}
```

See also: [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) and [`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

Change it to

```
if ($('#mobile-view').is(":visible")) {

    $("#product-info").insertAfter("#product-gallery");
} else {
     $("#product-gallery").insertAfter("#product-info");
 }
```

Comment: isn't it right if visible insert after product gallery or else insert after product-info?

Comment: it seems that the OP has posted the inverse condition : if `#mobile-view` is invisible then we insert the product gallery...

Comment: he say this if ($('#mobile-view').css('visibility') === 'hidden') {
        $("#product-gallery").insertAfter("#product-info");
    }  that means if hidden then insert after product info ? Correct?

Comment: Yes correct, but your logic is if **visible**, then insert after product info... :)

Comment: No :) if Visible do this $("#product-info").insertAfter("#product-gallery"); that is insert after product gallery.

Comment: Oh sorry I have not seen that you have inverted the 2 blocks :-) You're right!

Comment: Okay..Cool It was healthy conversation. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use hasClass

```
if ($('#mobile-view').hasClass(className)) {
 // put your logic inside this.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$("#mobile-view").is(":visible") == true`